# Gsuite App integration: Identify company/domain of user

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

I'm integrating my web application into gsuite (fka google apps marketplace) and I'm not sure how to handle the user creation flow.

At first the admin of a domain adds my app and goes through the initial authorization steps (scopes, TOS,notify users). As far as I understand there is no communication with my site at this point.

At the end of there is a link urging the admin to complete the setup on my site. 
When the admin opens this link I can run him through oauth and get his tokens.

But this is where I'm stuck now: 
How do I identify the domain/company the admin and company users belong to?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but have you read the [Identify your domain host](https://support.google.com/a/answer/48323?hl=en) for G Suite?

Comment: I'm also trying to find a clear indicator of how this would work in the documentation. Did you have any luck? Thus far I'm thinking I need to take the user through the usual OAuth flow, then pull down their User Resource and work from the CustomerID or domains(s) from their Organization(s).

Comment: see my answer for my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% happy, but this is what I ended up doing: 
After receiving the tokens, I fire of a request to plus/people api and explicitly require the domain field.

```
var fields = 'id,name,language,domain,image,emails';
plus.people.get({ userId: 'me', auth: client, fields:fields }, ..
```

The domain is then what I use to identify the company with.

The customerId would be better, but I have not found a way to retrieve it without being a google admin.